# python: move menu item in pythondialog or urwid

Tags: python, curses

Is it possible to move item in a pythondialog menu or in a listbox with urwid? More precisely, I have to handle task priorities in a dialog box (that is why I thought about pythondialog, curses or urwid) and if I move up a task (a task name in fact), with the key-up keyboard (for example), it will be considered as more important than the task just below. It is like when one change a boot priority order in bios. It is the same idea.
The tasks name are not editable, one can just reorder them.

Comment: Please show what have you tried?

Comment: That's the point : i searched and i didnt found any kind of solution or workaround. I mainly searched in pythondialog, curses and urwid docs. I only found methods to add strings in the terminal or move them according to some given coordinates. So far, Im able to print strings in the terminal and edit them with pythondialog (editbox_str widget)

Comment: Searching with a web-browser isn't **programming**.  If you studied the source code, you might discover the methods available (which for your application probably require re-displaying the list with new contents).

Comment: I found that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807808/highlighting-and-selecting-text-with-python-curses) which helped me a lot.